# Rework this part of the regex to match the empty string?

Tags: regex

I want to fetch out the bucket and key from the S3 URL: `s3://bucket/key`

Here is the solution, but it doesn't match the empty string:

`(s3?://)([^:^/]*)?(.*)?")`

Here my question is, **How to include empty string?**

Answer (score 0):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following regex. Explanation here would be, matching s3 followed by : 2 slashes and then creating 2 capturing groups. Where 1st one will have bucket(vale before next /) and 2nd one will have value before next slash here.

```
s3:\/\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/nkDczM/1)

---

***2nd solution:*** Above will take `key` value till next occurrence of `/` in case its the last value of your url then try following: Explanation here would be, matching s3://, then creating 2 capturing groups where 1st one will have bucket value(before next /) and next one will have everything till end of url.

```
s3:\/\/([^\/]*)\/(.*)$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/J8WpEK/1)